# Error response from daemon: No build stage in current context

Tags: docker, kvm

I was trying to run a container with kvm, using the code I found here: https://github.com/jessfraz/dockerfiles/tree/master/kvm
I created a new directory, cd'd into it and created the dockerfile and start.sh files.
When I gave order to build, it outputted the following error message:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.584kB
Error response from daemon: No build stage in current context
```

I have no idea what this means and I couldn't Google an answer.
Any help?

Answer (score 375):

Does your dockerfile have a: `FROM repo/image`

As the first line? I got this error when I forgot to specify the docker image that I was building from.

Even if you're building a "source image" you still need to specify `FROM scratch` as the first line of the dockerfile.

Comment: I had this problem because I was setting ENV for the debian frontend before the FROM command. Thanks!

Comment: @adamconkey there's a special case where you're allowed to have ARG before a FROM. That's the only thing that's allowed to be before FROM. Here's some more information about that: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact

Comment: It's not necessarily the FIRST line. It's just got to be the first non-comment line. Check my answer for a link to the official documentation with an explanation.

Comment: @NoBrainer In computer programming, the term "first line" almost always refers to the first non-comment line.

Comment: My first time using `LABEL`. Now I know it needs to be below a `FROM` statement 

Comment: It can also happen if you have more than 1 ARG before the first FROM

Answer (score 54):

This usually happens because of the text that is written before the FROM command. Try removing the comments in your dockerfile and build again.

For reference https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/164

Comment: This was my issue exactly, for some reason even the stuff I had commented out was causing it to throw this error. I removed it all and works fine now.

Comment: Comments haven't caused me any issues. Check my answer for a link to the official documentation with an explanation.

Answer (score 44):

This message appears when you declare an environment variable (`ENV`) before declaring `FROM`.

For example:

```
# Define variables.
ARG PORT
ENV SERVER_PORT=$PORT

# Install minimal Python 3.
FROM python:3.7-alpine

# Install Python requirements.
COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

# Copy app source code.
COPY src/ /app
...
```

To resolve this, swap the declarations so that any environment variables are set after `FROM`.

```
# Install minimal Python 3.
FROM python:3.7-alpine

# Define variables.
ARG PORT
ENV SERVER_PORT=${PORT}

# Install Python requirements.
COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

# Copy app source code.
COPY src/ /app
...
```

Answer (score 27):

According to the [documentation on docs.docker.com](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/reference/builder/#from), the first non-comment line of your Dockerfile must be the `FROM` line. To quote the docs:

> The `FROM` instruction initializes a new build stage and sets the [Base Image](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/reference/glossary/#base-image) for subsequent instructions. As such, a valid `Dockerfile` must start with a `FROM` instruction.

Comment: use either `FROM anyBaseImage` or use `FROM scratch`

Answer (score 25):

If you are still using the deprecated `MAINTAINER` keyword, you must have the `FROM` command as the first command in the `Dockerfile`:

**BAD**:

```
MAINTAINER your name "your@email.com"
FROM dockerimagename
```

**GOOD**:

```
FROM dockerimagename
MAINTAINER your name "your@email.com"
```

Comment: BTW note that the `MAINTAINER` keyword is deprecated since years.

Comment: @ValerioBozz, thank you for this note. would you suggest to add a note regarding deprecation and keep this for legacy code or shall we simply drop the answer? I think we can delete this :)

Comment: @Curious_Watcher I tried to edit the answer to put this note that may be still useful on old versions of Docker.

Answer (score 12):

The problem is resolved.
When I went to dockerfile to edit the code I noticed that I accidentally uncommented the first line. Stupid mistake, I know.
Thank you both for the help.

Answer (score 8):

It was my case because I had `ENV` specified before `FROM` and as already mentioned, the `FROM` should be the first expression in your Dockerfile.

BUT

Since this PR https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/31352 you can specify `ARG` before `FROM` which might be suitable alternative for you.

So I've changed

```
ENV MY_VAR 1
FROM ...
```

to

```
ARG MY_VAR=1
FROM ...
```

---

BTW You can read about ARG vs ENV difference here https://vsupalov.com/docker-arg-vs-env/

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that this is your case, but it might help someone else with that error.

1. My Dockerfile ran without that error.
2. I added "FROM vcatechnology/linux-mint:18.2" to the start of the Dockerfile, no error either.
3. After deleting that FROM statement again, it was still searching for it, causing this error.
4. I could only get rid of the error by adding the FROM statement again.

*Thus, this error can simply appear if you have used a Dockerfile starting with a FROM statement and if you then drop that FROM statement again.*

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I changed RUN to FROM.

Old Dockerfile:

```
RUN php:8-apache

COPY /src var/www/html/

ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT ./src/public/

RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf

RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf

EXPOSE 80
```

New Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8-apache

COPY /src var/www/html/

ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT ./src/public/

RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf

RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf

EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: Hi @Ivandez. The `RUN` has no sense with an image argument as far as i know. It's very difficult to pretend that the original questioner had your same problem.

Answer (score -2):

I removed all the comments in the Dockerfile and it worked just fine