# For a container running on Raspberry Pi what should I put in the FROM line?

Tags: raspberry-pi, dockerfile

I am building a Docker container and each time I try to build it, I get this error:

> Error response from daemon: no build stage in current context

Here's what my Dockerfile looks like:

```
RUN apt-get update && \
   apt-get -y install openvpn && \
   type -p resolvconf >/dev/null || apt-get -y install resolvconf
    
 CMD ["openvpn", "--config", "openvpnconfig.ovpn", "--script-security", "2", "--up", "/etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf", "--down", "/etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf"]
```

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50453357/7771746), which says I need a `FROM` line at the top.

Some examples I have seen say stuff like `FROM ubuntu:14.04` or `FROM ubuntu:latest` or another existing image.
Since I am not pulling from an existing image, what would I put there? I'm running it on a Raspberry Pi, so not using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

With your Pi Command line you can try this command

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep model
```

This should return the model of the CPU used in pi, something like `model name: ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)`

Now with Variant, `cat /etc/os-release` ,you may have “jessie” or “wheezy” variants

The output you care about here is

```
...
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
...
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
...
```

Now you can look at [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/search?q=arm32v7) for the `ARMv7` or whatever you have it. And according to your need, you can select what you pull image `FROM` according to your variant

For example, If you are using `ARMv7` and you need `python2.7` and `jessie` is your variant, You can add this `FROM` to the top of your `Dockerfile`

```
FROM arm32v7/python:2.7.13-jessie
```

Comment: The CPU model doesn't appear to be in /proc/cpuinfo, but I *think* it's ARM64--is there another way I can check?

Comment: According to `lscpu`, the cpu is `arch64`.

`/etc/os-release` says it's version 11 (bullseye), but there doesn't appear to be any images for [arm64v11](https://hub.docker.com/search?q=arm64v11).

Do I *have* to use one exactly for my arch/version, or will one for a different CPU work?